# How to prevent exception and class name conflict in R?

Tags: r

It just came to my attention that if in R I were to write something like this

```
tryCatch({
    myfunc()
  }, NotCoverged = function(e) {}
)
```

Some issues would arise if myfunc() has the following scenario:

```
myfunc <- function() {
     package1::operation()
     package2::another_operation()
}
```

now imagine that both `package1` and `package2` have a condition called `NotConverged`, with the exact same name. Obviously, `package1::operation` stops with its own `package1 NotConverged`, and `package2::another_operation` stops with its own `package2 NotConverged`.  I would not be able to differentiate if the first call or the second call has raised it. Resolution is only done by name, and the tryCatch handler would be called regardless, and would not be able to differentiate.

Similar situation may occur with class names in S3 resolution: if I have two packages defining the same class name. e.g. package1 defines:

```
create_obj <- function() {
    obj <- new.env()
    class(obj) <- c("whatever")
}
```

and a completely unrelated package2 also defines

```
create_obj <- function() {
    obj <- new.env()
    class(obj) <- c("whatever")
}
```

if each package defines `print.whatever` as an S3 method, what happens if I call, in my code that uses both package1 and package2, `print(package1::create_obj())` vs `print(package2::create_obj())`? It is my understanding it's "whoever got imported first" so you might end up calling the S3 method for the package1 `whatever` passing a package2 `whatever` object, which would likely be very bad, as they are completely unrelated with the exception of the name collision.

Are there any rules or code practice that namespaces conditions and class names in packages so that collisions between unrelated packages cannot occur?

Comment: There is the facility to differentiate your class from S3 classes from other packages by using `className`, which stores the package name too. You can control generic dispatch using this and `setMethod`. The problem is that this relies on package writers to stick to this pattern (which they don't), so clashes can and do occur. S3 is flexible enough that there are work arounds when clashes are identified, but there are conceivably situations in which you might get unexpected clashes.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks, could you link me to an example of its use, so I can try to play with it? the only link that seems relevant is on datamentor, but I can't reach it.

Comment: I mean, it seems that what it does is just to resolve the class. But that would still not solve the exception catching, for example.

Comment: No, it wouldn't solve the exception catching. There is more sophisticated exception catching via the `rlang` package.

Comment: @AllanCameron like catch_cnd? I don't see how it would solve. seems rather redundant to be honest...